# Cancel button to previous page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I currently have this cancel button that when the user clicks it - it will take them to the previous page they were on. If they made changes to the page without saving and then click cancel, a window will pop up asking if they want to leave the page without saving the changes. When 'Yes leave page' is clicked the message appears again and I have to click yes again. So the same message twice not sure why this is happening and if there is a better way to go back to a previous page.

Here is my code for the cancel button :

```
<a href="javascript:goBack(); " class="glossyBtn">
 <img alt="" style="vertical-align: middle" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/cross.png")%>" />
    <span style="vertical-align: middle">Cancel</span>
</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function goBack() {
        window.history.back();
    }
</script>
```

Also if a person is on a page and they make changes then save - the same page is reloaded with saved information but if the user clicks cancel they are taken back to the same page before the load and have to click cancel again to get all the way out of the page. Is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 3):

`window.history.back();` won't work as you expect. If you want to redirect to previous page then use `window.location`

```
 function goBack() {
        window.location = 'YOUR URL'; //specify the url to redirect
 }
```

**UPDATE to your comment:**

Yes, just pass the argument to the function.

```
function goBack(url) {
       window.location = url; //specify the url to redirect
}
```

In your `<a>` tag call the function like this,

```
<a href="javascript:goBack('http://www.stackoverflow.com'); " class="glossyBtn">
```

Comment: and if i am using the same button on multiple pages and depending what page is displayed the location url will be different. Is there a way to make it detect rather than manually writing a specific url?

Comment: This is great and will work for certain pages which i applied but there are three different pages with different paths that i use the same button so if i entered a 'http://....' it will be too specific.

Comment: `http://` is not required for redirecting internal website pages. You can simple use, `window.location = "/mypage/login.php";`. And `http://` is required for redirecting to external websites.

Answer (score 0):

`history.back()` wont work if browsers history is cleared manually, so go for window.location.href